# Gardening Android app

Tags: android, images, information-management, gardening

I am looking for an Android app that allows you to keep track of plants and vegetables grown in one's own garden as follows:

- For each garden location (which could be a square or rectangular area our a location by the fence or hedge), store a sequence of timestamped pictures showing how the cross our flowers grow over time.
- Store each sequence of such pictures inside a vertical list of head-of-the-list pictures which when clicked brings you to all the pictures and notes for that crop or flower planted in the given garden area.
- Optionally, allow the head-of-the-list pictures to be arranged in a rectangular area representing the field or hedge area where the crops are planted.
- Optionally, allow for the addition of an unlimited number of fields.

Comment: Not sure for this specific requirements – but while waiting for good and matching recommendations, be welcome to take a look at my app-list for [Gardening and plants](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/domestic_garden) :)